# problem with some commands using minted in beamer class

Tags: beamer, minted

I'm currently working on a presentation about LaTeX, which I am obviously writing in LaTeX with the beamer-class. So I thougt about including the package minted. This went without problems and works on my computer, but when I want to print `\par` or `% comment` via `\mint{LaTeX}|...|` my distribution does not recognize that I want to print it an returns a lot of errors that don't make any sense. Does anybody of you know, why there is only a problem with these two commands, but not with for example `\\`?

I removed these two commands and my file worked after a few tries again without any problems. So it has to be something about the combination of `\par` and `minted`. Including options like `[fragile]` into frame does not help either.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \mint{LaTeX}|\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}|
        \mint{LaTeX}|\par|
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal reproducible example which allows us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: When I compile this, I get errors. Leaving the line with \par out does not compute any errors. Btw I am using TeXStudio

Comment: It works fine for me if I add the `fragile` frame option https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAbmt.png

Comment: with \begin{frame}[fragile] and a complation with pdflatex -shell-escape nameoffile, it work fine for me.

Comment: Apparently there was a problem with my distribution. When I tried it again today, it worked fine. I will let you know if it happens again. But thanks anyway.